# How do I block a certain package from being installed without disabling recommends?

Tags: package-management, blacklist

I want to blacklist the package `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` forever.

How can I make sure upgrading my system will never install this package without disabling other "recommends" from being installed?

It must never be installed on my system and no attempt to install it must ever be made. The user should not need to decline the EULA acceptance manually. No package manager must ever install it, no matter which one I use.

Comment: I'm not sure why during upgrades you are requested to install new packages. Are you sure this happens during upgrade and not when you are installing some restricted software? Are you sure that package isn't already installed or partially configured?